# Jenkins TFS plugin throws NumberFormatException

Tags: tfs, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

When I do a poll from Visual Studio Online using the Jenkin TFS Plugin I get the following message and exception.

I use TEE-CLC on Ubuntu 12.10.

> ```
> No history entries were found for the item and version combination specified.
> FATAL: For input string: "" 
> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" 
> at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source) 
> at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source) 
> at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Project.getRemoteChangesetVersion(Project.java:200)
> at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Project.getRemoteChangesetVersion(Project.java:214)
> at hudson.plugins.tfs.TeamFoundationServerScm.checkout(TeamFoundationServerScm.java:189)
> at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1415) 
> at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:652)
> at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
> at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:561)
> at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1678) 
> at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46) 
> at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88) 
> at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:231)
> ```

Does anyone know what to do about it?

Answer (score 1):

Elsewhere on the internet answers suggest it's due to a lack of a specific workspace or credentials.

If the previous commands have worked, then is most likely due to a lack of revisions pulled into the local workspace. This may have been caused by the user's lack of read permissions for these.

For me, rather ridiculously it was caused by an incorrect sever clock (set in the past) on the the Jenkins host this caused the previous 'get' command to request revisions before the current server time; which was actually earlier than any code commits to the specific location.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to double check project path TFS url for any possible spelling mistakes. I had a spelling mistake in the path, caused the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

I would also to see how any spaces in the TFS project name come through in the log. In this line in my log:

```
[MySlaveJob02] $ tf history "$/PONTIAC RDSDSMyProject_Name" -recursive -stopafter:1 -noprompt -version:D2015-03-07T19:31:42Z -format:brief ********
```

The space is visible, other times when it wasn't working, it was a %20