# Sporadic issue: Jenkins TFS plugin throws NumberFormatException

Tags: jenkins, tfs, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am checking out the code via TFS plugin in Jenkins pipeline. But it gives a SPORADIC error.
It works perfectly fine when I rebuild the job.

Error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.DigitList.getLong(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.DecimalFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.subParse(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.util.datetime.LenientDateTimeParser.parseExtended(LenientDateTimeParser.java:285)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.util.datetime.LenientDateTimeParser.parse(LenientDateTimeParser.java:365)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.versioncontrol.specs.version.DateVersionSpec.<init>(DateVersionSpec.java:51)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.versioncontrol.specs.version.VersionSpec.parseSingleVersionFromSpec(VersionSpec.java:197)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.commands.RemoteChangesetVersionCommand.call(RemoteChangesetVersionCommand.java:60)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.commands.RemoteChangesetVersionCommand.call(RemoteChangesetVersionCommand.java:34)
    at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:45)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Server.execute(Server.java:233)
Caused: java.lang.RuntimeException
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Server.execute(Server.java:237)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Project.extractChangesetNumber(Project.java:280)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Project.getRemoteChangesetVersion(Project.java:276)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Project.getRemoteChangesetVersion(Project.java:292)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.TeamFoundationServerScm.recordWorkspaceChangesetVersion(TeamFoundationServerScm.java:394)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.TeamFoundationServerScm.checkout(TeamFoundationServerScm.java:343)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:124)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:93)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:80)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Snippet used:

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(
    credentialsId: 'amer-o9-ServiceAdmin',
    passwordVariable: 'pass',
    usernameVariable: 'user'
)]) {
    def secret = hudson.util.Secret.fromString(pass)

    checkout(
        changelog: false,
        scm: [
            $class: 'TeamFoundationServerScm',
            localPath: '\\',
            userName: user,
            password: secret,
            projectPath: '$/my_workspace/my_project',
            serverUrl: properURL,
            useUpdate: true,
            workspaceName: "HUDSON-${env.JOB_NAME}-${env.NODE_NAME}"
        ]
    )
}
```

P.S. There is no issue with the workspace path.

- Jenkins version: 2.204.2
- TFS-plugin version: 5.157.1

Looked for solutions here:

- [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21278265/11415785)
- [Jenkins issues](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21460)

Does anybody know what am I missing?

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue stably?  `But it gives a SPORADIC error. It works perfectly fine when I rebuild the job.` Did you mean it failed first time, then succeed second time? Or it just failed randomly?

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT It fails randomly... I will say it fails 1 out of 10 times.

Comment: Thanks. According to your description and comment. If it failed 1 out of 10 times, this should not related to TFS build pipeline configuration. Since it succeed. Then it may related to some other factors such as your build agent network environment, build agent hardware limitation. Kindly check this.